# Unable to start a Spark session in Jupyter

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, anaconda, jupyter-lab

I have installed pyspark in anaconda, ran findspark.init() and there is no issue.
But when running the pyspark shell, the spark variable (SparkSession) takes way too long to be created, so much so that at some point the code just stops running without the variable being created.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkOvi.png)
I tried again yesterday, it tooks all the day and didn't even work,
I have tried everything, restarting my computer, closing my Jupyterlab session but I still have the same problem. Could someone please help me?

Comment: It looks like you might just have a very slow hard drive, slow (or maybe busy) CPU, or too little free memory.  Please wait some more time and it should work fine then, try to close all other applications while waiting.

Comment: Hi, I have tried it but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
echo "export SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/spark-${SPARK:6:6}" >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PYTHONPATH=$(ZIPS=("$SPARK_HOME"/python/lib/*.zip); IFS=:; echo "${ZIPS[*]}"):$PYTHONPATH' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```